# Are we allowed to have <ruby> tags inside of html <p> tags?

Tags: html

In the [MDN Web Docs for ruby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby), it states that the permitted parents are:

> Permitted parents     Any element that accepts phrasing content.

However, when I follow that link to see what elements are considered [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), the `<p>` tag is not listed.

So, does this mean that in order for me to use the `<ruby>` tags, I should wrap them in `<span>` tags for example? With and without, they both seem to be rendering properly.

Without span

```
<p>The word of the day is <ruby>
  明日 <rp>(</rp><rt>Ashita</rt><rp>)</rp>
  </ruby></p>
```

With span

```
<p>The word of the day is <span><ruby>
  明日 <rp>(</rp><rt>Ashita</rt><rp>)</rp>
  </ruby></span></p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby), `<ruby>` is a type of *phrasing content* and is allowed inside any element that allows phrasing content. And the [permitted content type for `<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) is phrasing content. So `<ruby>` is allowed inside of `<p>`.

[That link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) you were looking at is not a list of tags which allow phrasing content. It's a list of elements which *are* phrasing content, including `<ruby>` but excluding `<p>`. `<p>` falls in a broader category called [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content), so you can embed a `<ruby>` inside of a `<p>` but it would be illegal to embed a `<p>` inside of a `<ruby>` or even a `<p>` inside of a `<p>`.